# iron-iconset svg file with all icons Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, polymer

I would like to know if it's possible to use `iron-iconset` to set multiple icons from an external svg file which contain all my icons? (One line correspond to a specific icon with all its declination (color, state etc...)). And each line is a specific icon

Something like:

```
<iron-iconset name="login" src="icons.svg" width="90" size="30" icons="normal invalid"></iron-iconset>
```

With `width` : the width of my svg file, `size` : the size of my logos square and somewhere to tell the height of the file and which line I want to use?

I hope it's clear enough, tell me if it's not.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I juste have to use `_offset-y` to use the right line :

```
<iron-iconset name="ci-login" src="/src/themes/autovision/icons_autovision.svg" width="90" size="30" _offset-y="30" icons="normal invalid"></iron-iconset>
```